# How do you pattern match a string in a vector?

Tags: c++, regex, vector

I have data in a vector and I need to see if it has the word Buy or Sell in the 3rd element vrecord[2]

What is the most straight forward way to look for the occurrences of a string inside a vector?

data:

```
198397685
2014-11-14 15:10:13
Buy
0.00517290
0.00100000
0.00100000
0.00000517
198398295
2014-11-14 15:11:14
Buy
0.00517290
0.00100000
0.00100000
0.00000517
203440061
2014-11-21 16:13:13
Sell
0.00825550
0.00100000
0.00100000
0.00000826
```

code:

```
    vector<std::string> vrecords;
    while(std::fgets(buff, sizeof buff, fp) != NULL){
            vrecords.push_back(buff);
    }

    for(int t = 0; t < vrecords.size(); ++t){
            cout << vrecords[t] << " ";
    }
```

Comment: `if(vrecords[2] == "Buy" || vrecords[2] == "Sell")` ? regex would be overkill here imo ..

Comment: @bro Show how the vector is defined.

Comment: vector<std::string> vrecords;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all it is a bad idea to use the C i/o system in C++. It would be better to use C++ function `std::getline` or member functions `getline` and/or `get` of class `std::basic_istream`.

Take into account that C function `fgets` stores also the new line character in the string. You should remove it. For example

```
while ( std::fgets( buff, sizeof buff, fp ) != NULL )
{
    size_t n = std::strlen( buff );
    if ( n && buff[n-1] == '\n' ) buff[n-1] = '\0';    
    if ( buff[0] != '\0' ) vrecords.push_back( buff );
}
```

If the vector is declared like `std::vector<std::string>` (I hope it is not declared as for example `std::vector<char *>`) then you could write instead

```
std::string record;
while ( std::getline( YourFileStream, record ) )
{
    if ( !record.empty() ) vrecords.push_back( record );
}
```

In this case to find word "Buy" is simple using standard algorithm `std::find` declared in header `<algorithm>`. For example

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

//...

auto it = std::find( vrecords.begin(), vrecords.end(), "Buy" );

if ( it != vrecords.end() ) 
{
    std::cout << "Word \"" << "Buy"
              << "\" is found at position " 
              << std::distance( vrecords.begin(), it )
              << std::endl;  
}
```

If you need to find any of the following words Buy or Sell  then you may use standard algorithm `std::find_first_of`. for example

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

//...

const char * s[] = { "Buy", "Sell" };

auto it = std::find_first_of( vrecords.begin(), vrecords.end(), 
                              std::begin( s ), std::end( s ) );

if ( it != vrecords.end() ) 
{
    std::cout << "One of the words \"" << "Buy and Sell"
              << "\" is found at position " 
              << std::distance( vrecords.begin(), it )
              << std::endl;  
}
```

If you need to count how many there are such words in the vector then you can use the above aproaches in a loop or use standard algorithms `std::count`, `std::count_if`, `std::accumulate` or a range based for loop.
 For example

```
const char * s[] = { "Buy", "Sell" };

auto n = std::count_if( vrecords.begin(), vrecords.end(),
                        [&]( const std::string &record )
                        { 
                            return record == s[0] || record == s[1];
                        } );
```

Comment: Your code shows 1 buy, but it should show 3. There are 3 buys in that data stream.  https://bpaste.net/show/b5c55bcad687  :(

Comment: @bro Please read what you wrote yourself: " I have data in a vector and I need to see if it has the word Buy or Sell "